# Nested groupby using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I would like to sum the energy values for US, China and Japan and label this 'group1'
Then groupby date, country, type and sum the energy values.

**Data**

We are grouping by date, and type and taking the sum of these specific countries: US, China and Japan - renaming this combination as group1

```
date        country    type energy
8/1/2022    US         aa   10
8/1/2022    US         aa   11
8/1/2022    China      bb   50
8/1/2022    Japan      bb   20
10/1/2022   Australia  bb   5
```

**Desired**

```
date        country   type  energy
8/1/2022    group1    aa    21
8/1/2022    group1    bb    70
10/1/2022   Australia bb    5
```

**Doing**

```
df.groupby(['country','date', 'type'], as_index=False).agg({'energy': sum})
```

The above script performs the groupby and sum perfectly, but unsure of how to condense certain categories into a group before doing this step.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine them, how about just filter first and change the value to `group1` and then do the groupby?

```
df.loc[df['country'].isin(['US', 'China', 'Japan']), 'country'] = 'group1'
df.groupby(['date', 'type', 'country'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({'energy': sum})
```

```
        date type    country  energy
0   8/1/2022   aa     group1      21
1   8/1/2022   bb     group1      70
2  10/1/2022   bb  Australia       5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# define a dictionary to group the countries
d={'US': 'Group-1',
   'China':'Group-1',
   'Japan' :'Group-1'}

# create a group column, based on mapping
# keeping a separate column, to avoid losing original values
# it can very well be a country
df['group']=df['country'].map(d).fillna(df['country'])

# do a groupby
out= df.groupby(['group','date', 'type'], as_index=False).agg({'energy': sum})
```

```
    group           date    type    energy
0   Australia   10/1/2022   bb      5
1   Group-1     8/1/2022    aa     21
2   Group-1     8/1/2022    bb     70
```